# Converting FFmpeg frame to OpenGL ES texture

Tags: android, ffmpeg, textures

I'm trying to convert from a video using FFmpeg to an OpenGL ES texture in jni, but all that I get is a black texture. I have output the OpenGL with the `glGetError()`, but there is no error.

Here is my code:

```
void* pixels;
int err;
int i;
int frameFinished = 0;
AVPacket packet;
static struct SwsContext *img_convert_ctx;
static struct SwsContext *scale_context = NULL;
int64_t seek_target;

 int target_width = 320;
 int target_height = 240;
 GLenum error = GL_NO_ERROR;
 sws_freeContext(img_convert_ctx);  

i = 0;
while((i==0) && (av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet)>=0)) {
        if(packet.stream_index==videoStream) {
        avcodec_decode_video2(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &frameFinished, &packet);

        if(frameFinished) {
            LOGI("packet pts %llu", packet.pts);
            img_convert_ctx = sws_getContext(pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height, 
                   pCodecCtx->pix_fmt, 
                   target_width, target_height, PIX_FMT_RGB24, SWS_BICUBIC, 
                   NULL, NULL, NULL);
            if(img_convert_ctx == NULL) {
                LOGE("could not initialize conversion context\n");
                return;
            }
                sws_scale(img_convert_ctx, (const uint8_t* const*)pFrame->data, pFrame->linesize, 0, pCodecCtx->height, pFrameRGB->data, pFrameRGB->linesize);
                LOGI("sws_scale");

                videoTextures = new Texture*[1];
                videoTextures[0]->mWidth = 256; //(unsigned)pCodecCtx->width;
                videoTextures[0]->mHeight = 256; //(unsigned)pCodecCtx->height;
                videoTextures[0]->mData = pFrameRGB->data[0];

                glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

                glGenTextures(1, &(videoTextures[0]->mTextureID));
                glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, videoTextures[0]->mTextureID);
                glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR); 
                glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

                if(0 == got_texture)
                {
                    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, videoTextures[0]->mWidth, videoTextures[0]->mHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid *)videoTextures[0]->mData);

                    glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0,0, videoTextures[0]->mWidth, videoTextures[0]->mHeight, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid *)videoTextures[0]->mData);
                }else
                {
                    glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0,0, videoTextures[0]->mWidth, videoTextures[0]->mHeight, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid *)videoTextures[0]->mData);

                }

                i = 1;
                error = glGetError();
                if( error != GL_NO_ERROR ) {
                    LOGE("couldn't create texture!!");
                       switch (error) {
                        case GL_INVALID_ENUM:
                        LOGE("GL Error: Enum argument is out of range");
                        break;
                        case GL_INVALID_VALUE:
                            LOGE("GL Error: Numeric value is out of range");
                        break;
                        case GL_INVALID_OPERATION:
                            LOGE("GL Error: Operation illegal in current state");
                        break;
                        case GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY:
                            LOGE("GL Error: Not enough memory to execute command");
                        break;
                        default:
                            break;
                       }
                }
        }
    }
    av_free_packet(&packet);
}
```

I have succeeded in changing pFrameRGB to a java bitmap， but I just want to change it to a texture in the c code.

**Edit1**  I have output the Texture ID, it is 0; could texture ID be zero? I changed my code
but it always be zero.

**Edit2**
the Texture display, but  it is a mess.

Answer (score 2):

Not used to GLES, but GL. In there 320, 240 are not valied 512,256 as to power of 2. Else you need to use texture_rectangle extension which texcoords are not from 0-1 but 0-w/h. As for uploading texture data, glTexImage(...) is needed to be used the first time (even with data 0), then glTexSubImage is enough, i think sizing etc is initialized with the first, the second just sends the meat.

Regarding ffmpeg usage, perhaps a version issue but img_context is more near to be renamed to sws_getContext, and initialized only once, if cpu usage is an issue use SWS_LINEAR instead of SWS_CUBIC, also i assume pFrameRGB has been correctly avcodec_alloc_frame()'ed, if you are going to use GL_RGBA you should use PIX_FMT_RGBA, PIX_FMT_RGB24 would be for GL_RGB texture piping, finally you lack a packet stack so you can go reading in advance to keep display good in sync and not late.

I've read some comments about unpack alignment, i didn't need that (and seeing the success in the area doubt of it) to implement an ffmpeg to OpenGL/OpenAL media library (http://code.google.com/p/openmedialibrary), nicely the audio bits have also been extracted to an ffmpeg to OpenAL loader (http://code.google.com/p/openalextensions). Haves some nice features and currently i'm trying to work with texture compression to see if it can perform still better. Consider that tutorials or even ready to use gpl code.

Hope to give some enlightenment on the obscure (by lack) art of ffmpeg to OpenGL/AL integration.

Answer (score 0):

Try to append 16 zero bytes to each packet before passing to decoder.

Some comments from the *avcodec.h*:

```c
 /*
 * @warning The input buffer must be FF_INPUT_BUFFER_PADDING_SIZE larger than
 * the actual read bytes because some optimized bitstream readers read 32 or 64
 * bits at once and could read over the end.
 * @warning The end of the input buffer buf should be set to 0 to ensure that
 * no overreading happens for damaged MPEG streams.
  */
```